# Toast-plugin is not working in cordova app

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, toast, back-button

I'm creating my cordova app where on clicking default back button in mobile app it should show a toaster notification that "Tap again to exit the app", then on clicking back button again it should exit the app.

I used the following plugin with some lines of code but it is not working.

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-toast

```
function showBottom() {
```

`window.plugins.toast.showWithOptions(` 
   `{`

```
  message: "Tap again to exit the app",
  duration: "short",
  position: "bottom",
  addPixelsY: -40  
},
onSuccess, 
onError    ); }
```

Expected Result : on clicking default back button in mobile app it should show a toaster notification that "Tap again to exit the app", then on clicking back button again it should exit the app.

Actual Result : It does not show any toast notification message.

Can anyone help me with the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's the exact code that should trigger the toast? i.e. the code bound to the `onBackKeyDown` event handler